# Activity with ListView and other elements

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I dont know how to set up my activity layour right. I have a layout with button at the top and when I click it I want to populate ListView to present some data(like history of ordered pizzas). But when I click button I get this:

[image]

I dont understand why this button keeps copying. I just want one at the top.

activity_tab_history.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tomek.pizzaservice.TabHistoryActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:id="@+id/buttRefresh"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="buttRefreshAction" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewItem" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttRefresh"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

code:

```
public void buttRefreshAction(View view){
    listView.setAdapter(loadDataFromDatabase());
}

private ArrayAdapter<String> loadDataFromDatabase(){
    Toast.makeText(TabHistoryActivity.this, "Loading orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_tab_history, R.id.textViewItem);

    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        arrayAdapter.add("Order date: 2000:01:" +(01+i)+
                ", pizza: " + (rand.nextInt(15)+1) +
                ". SOME PIZZA NAME BLA BLA BLA" +
                " Status: somthin");
    }

    Toast.makeText(TabHistoryActivity.this, "Completed loading orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return arrayAdapter;
}
```

Comment: How does `R.layout.activity_tab_history` look?

Comment: @Emmanuel it is this xml which I included.

Comment: Is the function leaving the activity then coming back in?

Comment: @DroidChris no, I use this activity in my tab "History". I want ListView just to present some data.

Comment: Can you post the layout of your list item?

Comment: post your  item layout .. the button is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling the adapter that the each row has the same layout as the whole thing.

look at

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_tab_history, R.id.textViewItem);
```

the second item given should be the layout for your row. it should be like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_row_template, R.id.textViewItem);
```

and the row template is another layout file which shows what you want each row to look like, on the other hand you could do this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
```

which will use the default android row layout of just a line of text

Comment: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` when I used it, it gave me NullPointerException

Comment: @Tomek oh sorry about that, you were supposed to use android.R.id.text1. i have changed my example above

Comment: Nice explanation, plus it's cool you provided example where I dont need to create another layout. Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell me in addition, what If I wanted to make some list items different than others, e.g. with green background ?

Comment: then you would have to use the custom layout option, and use setBackground to set the color. but that gets complicated with a simpleAdapter. you would probably need to use a custom ListAdapter

Answer (score 2):

You are using the entire history tab as your list item in the `ArrayAdapter`. So every time you're adding you're inflating the view with the button in it.

Make your list item something simple, that contains just a `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

If `R.layout.activity_tab_history` is the XML included, it contains a `Button`. This layout is the one being used as the layout to inflate for every row.

You are also including a `ListView` for every row item.